# javascript object - how to call class variable inside class function

Tags: javascript, oop, object

i want to call variable "info" when user click on div

the code supposed to print "success"

but its print "undefined"

*html*

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: solid black 1px">
```

*javascript*

```
window.onload = function(){

var Controller = function(){

    this.info = '  success  ';

    this.listener = function(){
        alert( this.info );
    }

    this.set = function( ele ){
        ele.onclick = this.listener;
    }
}


var target = document.getElementById('container');
var controller = new Controller();
    controller.set( target );



}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/areyouready/62qz6/1/)

my goal

- i need to call variable "info" inside *Controller listener*
- i need to give action click inside *Controller set*

my problem is 
inside function "listener",

keyword "this" refer to div element, not class Controller

how to call variable info inside function "*listener*" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var Controller = function(){
  var self = this; // Add this
  this.info = '  success  ';
  this.listener = function(){
    alert( self.info ); // Modify here
  }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind` to bind the function to the right `this`:

```
ele.onclick = this.listener.bind(this);
```